# Problems with making a completion block [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, void

I am trying to code a method with a completion block that returns the gathered data. I'm not sure if I'm just not doing it right or something else is the matter.

My method:

```
-(void)getAllUserDataWithUsername:(NSString *)username completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary     *))data {
```

I want to be able to set the NSDictionary to the recieved data and be able to get that data when I call this method somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Returns the gathered data to where?

Comment: What happens when you try to call your method? What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I want to be able to call that method from a different file/View controller and get the data back using that NSDictionary

Comment: @Tommy it works fine it just doesn't have any data in the NSDictionary because I'm not sure how to set it

Comment: The tiny snippet of code that you have included looks ok, however it is not much to go on. You need to return an instantiated `NSDictionary` object in the block e.g: `data(myDict)`. If you want further help you'll have to post more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight change to make for your declaration to be cleaner. `data` should be the name of the `NSDictionary` parameter and not the completion block name.

A step by step guide to declare, implement and call a method with a completion block would be as follows:

In your class header that implements the method you can declare the method:

```
- (void)getAllUserDataWithUsername:(NSString *)username 
                        completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary* data))completion;
```

Notice how `data` is the parameter passed in the block and `completion` is the name of the block.

In the implementation of your class you can do:

```
- (void)getAllUserDataWithUsername:(NSString *)username 
                        completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary* data))completion {
    // your code to retrieve the information you need
    NSDictionary *dict = //the data you retrieved
    // call the completion block and pass the data
    completion(dict); // this will be passed back with the block to the caller
}
```

Now in wherever you call this method you can do:

```
[myClass getAllUserDataWithUsername:@"username" completion:^(NSDictionary *data) {
    // data will be `dict` from above implementation
    NSLog(@"data = %@", data);
}];
```

Hope it helps.